# VBA Syntax Error in Update Statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I know that there are several questions about this, but I have looked at this line of code for several hours and cannot figure out the problem.  It keeps saying that there is a syntax error with this line of code, and I can't see it. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
 db.Execute "UPDATE Questions SET Date = #4/26/2014#,TwoChapt=False " & _
             " WHERE Book = '" & rs!Book & "' AND Chapter = '" & _
              rs!Chapter & "' AND QuestionType = 1 "
```

Comment: I'm not an expert (far from it!!), but isn't `Date` a reserved word and therefore will need to be coded as `[Date]` to indicate it is a field name?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) with querydefs and avoid interpolating values in your string:

**SQL** *(save as a stored Access query object)*

```sql
PARAMETERS BookParam Text(255), ChapterParam Text(255);
UPDATE Questions 
SET [Date] = #4/26/2014#, TwoChapt = False
WHERE Book = [BookParam] AND Chapter = [ChapterParam] AND QuestionType = 1;
```

**VBA** *(place within recordset loop except `Dim` AND `Set ... = Nothing`)*

```vb
...
Dim qdef As Querydef
Set qdef = Currentdb.Querydefs("MyStoredQuery")

Do While ...
  ' BIND PARAMS
  qdef!BookParam = rs!Book
  qdef!ChapterParam = rs!Chapter

  ' EXECUTE ACTION
  qdef.Execute, dbFailOnError
Loop  

Set qdef = Nothing
```